# How to pronounce "parlent-ils"

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

I am wondering: How do you pronounce "parlent-ils" correctly? I know that the ending "-ent" is usually mute. However, what about cases that usually require a liason?

Comment: *-ent* does indeed trigger liaison on the "t". To cite good old Daniel Lavoie: ["Mais c'est toujours les mêmes qui **semblenT** avoir raison"](http://ow.ly/T38o30bNJ9X) ("Long long", *Nirvana bleu*, 1979). Why just the "t"? Well, in these consonant clusters activated by liaison, the last consonant is generally the one pronounced. So similarly, in "grands arbres" you won't hear a "d" but you will hear a "z".

Comment: Does that mean, I'd pronounce it "parl til"?

Comment: @ThomasWening Misread your comment. That's correct. Laure: Good find. I don't think there's anything to add that isn't in that thread.

Comment: @ThomasWening "parl til" or "parleu til", like the singular third person "parle-t-il".

Comment: Thanks! This and the mentioned threat answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The '-nt' at the end of verb is always mute. 
*Parle* and *Parlent* have the same prononciation.

When you ask with the form verb-sujet-? You have to add a -t for a better sonority except when verb end by -t or -d :
- convainc-t-il ?
- prend-il ?
- cueille-t-il ?
- peut-il ?

For more informations on liaisons : [check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28French%29#Optional_liaison)

Comment: To be clearer, it's not always mute. The "t" you mention adding is to match the fact that in words that already end in "t", you pronounce it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have say "the '-nt' at the end of a verb at the last person of plurial is always mute".

Comment: ...when not in liaison circumstances!

Comment: Wrong- 'parlent' would be the same pronounciation if it was alone.  But in this case, you have to pronounce the 't' because of the liaison.